# open a file php from a console

Tags: c#, php

I have a file `.phar` and I want to run this file in Console application.

I use `Process` class. This is my code:

```
Process process = new Process(); 
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "file.phar";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "php prt 1111";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();
```

But it returns following error:

> The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'

(PHP is installed on my system)

and when I change `Filename` to:

```
 process.StartInfo.FileName = "php file.phar";
```

it returns error:

> The system cannot find the file specified'

in cmd windows By adding "php" to First of all, comments is ok.
how i can add "php" to First comment for start Process in Console C# ?

Comment: what if you specify the full path of file?

Comment: Have you added PHP.exe to you envoirment variables?

Comment: should it not be done like this: "php" is the file name of the executable, and everything else goes in `Arguments`?

Comment: well maybe because the executable is not a valid application for your OS platform??

Comment: btw. .phar is not an executable anywhere..

Comment: @TimonPost Yes I have already added

Comment: @oooas so what now?

Comment: @sLw in cmd windows It work comments like this (Respectively):

`cd newfolder`

`php file.phar`

`php prt 1111`

-------------------------------

now I want it with **Process** in Console C#

Comment: @oooas but you use php and not file.phar as the executable. change the filename to php and the argument to file.phar